# Problemas con el atributo required en un select

Tags: html, select, required

```
    <select id="decision" required>
                    <optgroup label="Resolucion de la solicitud">
                        <option value="">--Seleccionar--</option>
                        <option value="Aprobada">Aprobada</option>
                        <option value="Rechazada">Rechazada</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

He estado viendo en varios lugares que a la hora de poner el required en un select lo único que hay que hacer es dejar la primera opción con un valor vacío. Así lo hago pero no consigo que funcione. Alguna idea de lo que está pasando?

Comment: Ese select lo tienes dentro de un <form>?

Comment: ¿Cómo envias el form?  Solo funciona si está en un form y haces un submit

Answer (score 1):

Cambia la posición de la opción con valor no válido, la que indica que hacer:

```
<select id="decision" required>
                 <option value="">--Seleccionar--</option>
                 <optgroup label="Resolucion de la solicitud">                       
                        <option value="Aprobada">Aprobada</option>
                        <option value="Rechazada">Rechazada</option>
                  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Te debe funcionar

Comment: Perfecto así funciona! Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Me alegro, si quieres puedes marcar la respuesta como válida.